# Generate an Url after a select form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to generate an url in the same page that I have a selection form...
but I have two problems which I mention below the code.

Here's the code (and the snippet)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ca">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>url generator</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<select id='corpusname' size='1' name='corpusname' required />
<option value='btdees_de'>btdees_de</option>
<option value='btdees_es'>btdees_es</option>
<option value='btenes_en'>btenes_en</option>
<option value='btenes_es'>btenes_es</option>
</select>
<p>Url: https://iac.upf.edu/cddz/infogen/pages/<var id="corpusname"></var>.html</p>
<p><a href='https://iac.upf.edu/cddz/infogen/pages/<var id="corpusname"></var>.html'>Actual link</a></p>

<script>
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $( "var#corpusname" ).text( str );
  })
  .change();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Problem 1:** before the ".html" remains a space that I can not eliminate.

**Problem 2:** in pure text the url seems ok, except for the **problem 1**, but when trying to use it at the href attribute it just keeps the underlying code, I mean, it does not insert the text.

Am I doing something wrong or this is just not the way to do it, if so, which one could be a good way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of misusing HTML tags, do it like this:

```
<p>Url: <span id="plainUrl"></span></p>
<p><a id="actualLink">Actual link</a></p>
```

```
function updateContent() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var link = "https://iac.upf.edu/cddz/infogen/pages/" + value + ".html";

    $("#plainUrl").text(link);              // update plain text
    $("#actualLink").attr("href", link);    // update href
}

updateContent.call($("#corpusname").change(updateContent));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/9mce43jn/

Comment: Yessss! you made my day!

Comment: I hope my answer helped you.

Comment: It certainly did it!!

Answer (score 0):

it is coming from the line `str += $( this ).text() + " ";` try removing the last `" "`.

Comment: Thanks, anyway this code could not do what I needed, the one given in the previous answer is the correct one....